# How should i get an email when i submit the request form / submit form through html

Tags: html, email, html-email

i am working on a submit form in my html page. When i click submit button, i should get mail in my inbox.

So what all the procedures, i need to follow to get the output.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a server side language like PHP / ASP.NET etc. Then:

1. User submits form.
2. Retrieve the submitted information.
3. Send an email using the email functionality specific to the language you decide to use.

You haven't given much so this is only an outline of what you need to do to get going. You can  use Google for the various areas you need to implement.

Comment: Instead of using any server, is there any plugins which can be useful to get my output.

Comment: If there was a plugin you would still need to have it running on the server side as the client (the users browser) is unable to send emails. You can get some good references from Google. Just look for `Sending email using {language}`. It all depends on your server setup and which language you want to go with.

Answer (score 0):

> Instead of using any server, is there any plugins which can be useful
>   to get my output. – Bharadwaj

I think this might do the job for you http://www.emailmeform.com/

I've never used it, but it looks like a website that hosts the form for you and emails you the results. You'd just put the form html on your page and let them do the rest.

Hope that helps.